# Conversão de dado SSIS de varchar para int

Tags: sql, sql-server, integração, ssis

Estou travado em uma conversão pelo SSIS, cenário:

Tenho um arquivo CSV, que preciso importar pra uma tabela já criada no banco de dados,
Nesta tabela do banco tenho uma coluna já populada que recebe tipo de dados INT, observei que há registros com até 9 caracteres nesta coluna.

Estou tentando converter o dado deste CSV de varchar para inteiro, porém, nas opções de tipo de dados disponibilizadas pelo SSIS tenho no máximo eight-byte, que está me retornando o erro

```
[Data Conversion [55]] Error: Data conversion failed while converting column "CONTA" (10) to column "Copy of CONTA" (72).
The conversion returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data."”.
```

Alguém pode me ajudar ou me dar uma alternativa?

Comment: Já tentou importa tudo como varchar para uma tabela (temporária) e depois usar essa tabela pra fazer o select/insert na sua tabela de destino?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clica com o botão direito em cima da task que busca os dados do CSV e abre o Advanced Editor, ai tu vai na aba Input and Output Properties > Source > Output Columns > clica no campo que tu quer mudar o tipo > Na opção DataType tu muda do oque estiver para NUMERIC[DT_NUMERIC]